# Flask/Python error: attempted relative import with no known parent package when running Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I've tried commenting out as much as possible to eliminate any external problem.  I try running it using
`python manage.py runserver` and get the error:

```
File "app\manage.py", line 3, in <module>
  from .app import app
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

manage.py and app.py are in the same directory.  Line 3 is the app import line.

manage.py

```
from flask_script import Manager

from .app import app

manager = Manager(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="./static/dist", template_folder="./static")
```

If it means anything I've also run `Inspect Code` inside PyCharm and get no errors.

Comment: Actually, I think `from app import app` works here. Have you tried that before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `python something.py`, that file isn't considered to be part of a package --- only modules that are imported or are run with `python -m` are.

In this case the solution is probably to replace the line that tries to import your `app.py` with

```
from app.app import app
```

or

```
from app import app
```

... depending on what's in your `sys.path` and where your project folder is placed.

Comment: I still don't completely understand when to use the dot and when not to, but that fixed it.